# Show that the Möbius group (or general linear projective space $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$) is not simply connected.

Tags: lie-groups, mobius-transformation

How to show that the Möbius group (or the general linear projective space $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is not simply connected?

For a definition see: [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation). For more background see: [projective linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group).

According to [Applied Mathematical Sciences 61] D. H. Sattinger, O. L. Weaver (auth.) - Lie Groups and Algebras with Applications to Physics, Geometry, and Mechanics (1986, Springer-Verlag) there is a closed path that cannot be shrunk to a point.

The path is given by the Möbius transformations $z \mapsto z e^{2 \theta}$ for $\theta \in [0, \pi] $, I think. But how do I show that it cannot be shrunk to a point in (in the Möbius group)?

Comment: Do you already know how to prove that $SO(3)$ is not simply-connected? If you do, then use the existence of a diffeomorphism $PSL(2,C)\to R^3\times SO(3)$.

Comment: More generally, any Lie group $G$ is diffeomorphic to $M\rtimes \Bbb R^n$, where $M$ is a maximal compact subgroup (unique up to conjugacy).